SSH to instance without its floating IP address
Hello let's say i don't want to use floating IP adresses for some reasons.
I have set up routes using br-ex to connect to my instances.
My openstack server is at 10.90.0.236.
Now i have instance Test-VM (192.168.120.39):

Ping is working fine between them
I can ssh from Test-VM to my openstack server
But i can't connect to Test-VM from my openstack server (unless i use floating IP    adresses)

OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.120.39 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/stack/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/stack/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.120.39 [192.168.120.39] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/stack/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 192.168.120.39 port 22


Thank you

Security group restrictions on traffic to test-vm? Local firewall rules? If you run tcpdump on the test vm, do you see the packets arriving?

Some packet are arriving:
I put it in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/Fantarina/a1f355c35adabbfd2a56b0a0e3380ad0

Disabling SNAT on the virtual router did the trick.
IMO OpenStack should really do an effort on documentation

You probably have a firewall in between, that's too restrictive. Try to remove the firewall, to see if that's causing the issue. Next try to put the firewall back, rule-by-rule to see which rule is causing the issue.

Do you perhaps know how to disable the firewall in between?
Because I don't know where to search first :'(
